# Save cell changes in JTable ONLY if button pressed, if not stay as before

Tags: java, swing, jtable

If I select a row in the ABOVE JTable, then a row corresponding to that data will appear in the JTable BELOW. All the cells in the Jtable below are editable. What I need is:

If I press the button, changes in the Jtable BELOW will be saved. If I don't press the button, the JTable cells will remain as they were in the original state of the application.

PS: This is a demo, the real case contains much more parameters, but the purpose is the same.

```
    package guarreo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class demo extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable tablePATIENTS;
    private JTable tableREPORTS;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    demo frame = new demo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public demo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 571, 336);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        tablePATIENTS = new JTable();
        tablePATIENTS.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if(tablePATIENTS.getSelectedRow()!=-1){//If there is a patient selected with a report, enable the save changes button
                    DefaultTableModel dtm2 = (DefaultTableModel) tableREPORTS.getModel();
                    dtm2.addRow(new Object[]{"200$", "Pills", "Headache"});
                    tableREPORTS.setModel(dtm2);
                }
            }
        });
        tablePATIENTS.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
            },
            new String[] {
                "Name", "Surrname", "Doctor"
            }
        ));
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tablePATIENTS.getModel();
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{"Jon", "Snow", "Jack"});

        JButton btnSaveChanges = new JButton("Save changes tableREPORTS");
        btnSaveChanges.setEnabled(false);
        btnSaveChanges.setBounds(155, 260, 212, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSaveChanges);
        tablePATIENTS.setModel(dtm);
        tablePATIENTS.setBounds(20, 11, 486, 107);
        contentPane.add(tablePATIENTS);

        tableREPORTS = new JTable();
        tableREPORTS.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                btnSaveChanges.setEnabled(true); //Enabled only if something selected in this table
            }
        });
        tableREPORTS.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
            },
            new String[] {
                "Cost", "Treatment", "Disease"
            }
        ));
        tableREPORTS.setBounds(20, 144, 486, 105);
        contentPane.add(tableREPORTS);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a site where questions and answers that can help all are presented. In order for this question to help future users we ask that you post **all** pertinent information here with your question and not in links. Also, please understand that all who help here are volunteers, and we much appreciate your making it as easy as possible to understand your question, including not making us go to outside sites for information.

Comment: The best code to present is a [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org), since this would allow us to experience your problem first hand, and thus understand it much more completely.

Comment: `"I believe the code would go into the button "mouse clicked" event."` -- and I believe that you're wrong. This suggests that you're adding a MouseListener to your JButton when you should be using an ActionListener.

Comment: No, it does not help us. How can we compile or run code snippets? And no, we don't want the whole program either. Please read or re-read the links provided in my second comment as they will explain all.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's a dema you can compile and execute. It's debuggable, it's really basic, it represents what I need to do. If this doesn't work I don't know what else to do so I'll just delete the question

Comment: The code looks good, thanks, and 1+. I'm tied up at the moment but will look at it some more soon. Otherwise someone else will have a look at it and provide a decent answer.

Comment: See edits. It's a bit long, but illustrates the point.

Comment: Please let me know if anything is confusing. On further thought though, an AbstractTableModel might be better than using the DefaultTableModel since then the patient objects don't have to be re-created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution is to make a **deep** copy of the patient's data, and use this copy of the data to create your secondary JTable data. The user can then make whatever changes to the JTable data that they wish to do, without fear of side effect. Once the button is pressed, it's ActionListener then translates the JTable model's data back into the patient's data, replacing the original data. So the key is not to do this replacement until the button has been pressed.

If the Patient class holds an ArrayList of information class objects, and the getter for this list should make a **deep** copy by making a new ArrayList, and in a for loop, filling it with deep copy of objects held in the original list.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyDemo extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 3;
    private MyPatientTableModel patientModel = new MyPatientTableModel();
    private JTable patientTable = new JTable(patientModel);
    private JTable ptVisitTable = new JTable(new MyPtVisitTableModel(new ArrayList<MyPtVisit>()));

    public MyDemo() {
        MyPatient pt0 = new MyPatient("001", "Johnson", "Michael");
        pt0.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(200, "Head Ache", "Narcotics"));
        pt0.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(300, "Body Ache", "Aspirin"));
        pt0.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(400, "Total Ache", "Nothing"));

        MyPatient pt1 = new MyPatient("002", "Smith", "John");
        pt1.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(220, "Head Ache", "Narcotics"));
        pt1.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(320, "Body Ache", "Aspirin"));
        pt1.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(420, "Total Ache", "Nothing"));

        MyPatient pt2 = new MyPatient("003", "Baker", "Betty");
        pt2.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(240, "Head Ache", "Narcotics"));
        pt2.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(340, "Body Ache", "Aspirin"));
        pt2.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(440, "Total Ache", "Nothing"));

        MyPatient pt3 = new MyPatient("004", "Duck", "Donald");
        pt3.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(260, "Head Ache", "Narcotics"));
        pt3.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(360, "Body Ache", "Aspirin"));
        pt3.addVisit(new MyPtVisit(460, "Total Ache", "Nothing"));

        MyPatient[] pts = { pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3 };

        for (MyPatient myPatient : pts) {
            patientModel.addRow(myPatient);
        }

        patientTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        patientTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new PatientTableListener());
        TableColumnModel tcm = patientTable.getColumnModel();
        tcm.removeColumn(tcm.getColumn(3)); // visits column should be invisible

        patientTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        ptVisitTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        Dimension size = patientTable.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
        size = new Dimension(size.width, size.height / 2);
        patientTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(size);
        size = ptVisitTable.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
        size = new Dimension(size.width, size.height / 2);
        ptVisitTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(size);
        JScrollPane ptTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(patientTable);
        JScrollPane ptVisitScrollPane = new JScrollPane(ptVisitTable);

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new SaveChangesAction("Save Changes")));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(ptTableScrollPane);
        add(Box.createVerticalStrut(GAP));
        add(ptVisitScrollPane);
        add(Box.createVerticalStrut(GAP));
        add(btnPanel);
    }

    private class SaveChangesAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SaveChangesAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int index = patientTable.getSelectedRow();
            if (index < 0) {
                return;
            }

            // to capture edits not yet complete
            if (ptVisitTable.isEditing()) {
                CellEditor cellEditor = ptVisitTable.getCellEditor();
                if (cellEditor != null) {
                    cellEditor.stopCellEditing();
                }
            }
            index = patientTable.convertRowIndexToModel(index);
            MyPatient selectedPatient = patientModel.getPatient(index);

            MyPtVisitTableModel visitsModel = (MyPtVisitTableModel) ptVisitTable.getModel();
            List<MyPtVisit> visits = visitsModel.getVisits();
            selectedPatient.setVisits(visits);

            patientModel.setPatientAt(index, selectedPatient);
        }
    }

    private class PatientTableListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                return;
            }
            int index = patientTable.getSelectedRow();
            if (index < 0) {
                return;
            }
            index = patientTable.convertRowIndexToModel(index);
            MyPatient selectedPatient = patientModel.getPatient(index);
            List<MyPtVisit> visits = selectedPatient.getVisits();
            MyPtVisitTableModel visitsModel = new MyPtVisitTableModel(visits);
            ptVisitTable.setModel(visitsModel);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyDemo mainPanel = new MyDemo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPatientTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    public MyPatientTableModel() {
        super(MyPatient.HEADINGS, 0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyPatient getPatient(int index) {
        String patientId = (String) getValueAt(index, 0);
        String lastName = (String) getValueAt(index, 1);
        String firstName = (String) getValueAt(index, 2);

        // non-displayed data
        List<MyPtVisit> visits = (List<MyPtVisit>) getValueAt(index, 3);
        MyPatient patient = new MyPatient(patientId, lastName, firstName);
        patient.setVisits(visits);
        return patient;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (getRowCount() != 0 && getValueAt(0, columnIndex) != null) {
            return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
        } else {
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }

    public void addRow(MyPatient patient) {
        Vector<Object> rowData = new Vector<>();
        rowData.add(patient.getPatientId());
        rowData.add(patient.getLastName());
        rowData.add(patient.getFirstName());
        rowData.add(patient.getVisits()); // not displayed!
        addRow(rowData);

    }

    public void setPatientAt(int row, MyPatient patient) {
        setValueAt(patient.getPatientId(), row, 0);
        setValueAt(patient.getLastName(), row, 1);
        setValueAt(patient.getFirstName(), row, 2);
        setValueAt(patient.getVisits(), row, 3);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPtVisitTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    public MyPtVisitTableModel(List<MyPtVisit> visits) {
        super(MyPtVisit.HEADINGS, 0);
        for (MyPtVisit myPtVisit : visits) {
            addRow(myPtVisit);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (getRowCount() != 0 && getValueAt(0, columnIndex) != null) {
            return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
        } else {
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }

    public void addRow(MyPtVisit myPtVisit) {
        Vector<Object> rowData = new Vector<>();
        rowData.add(myPtVisit.getCost());
        rowData.add(myPtVisit.getSymptom());
        rowData.add(myPtVisit.getTreatment());
        addRow(rowData);
    }

    // extract data from table model
    public List<MyPtVisit> getVisits() {
        List<MyPtVisit> visits = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getRowCount(); i++) {
            double cost = (double) getValueAt(i, 0);
            String symptom = (String) getValueAt(i, 1);
            String treatment = (String) getValueAt(i, 2);
            visits.add(new MyPtVisit(cost, symptom, treatment));
        }
        return visits;
    }
}

// class that represents each patient
class MyPatient {
    public static final String[] HEADINGS = { "Patient ID", "Last Name", "First Name", "Visits" };
    private String patientId;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private List<MyPtVisit> visits = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyPatient(String patientId, String lastName, String firstName) {
        this.patientId = patientId;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getPatientId() {
        return patientId;
    }

    public void setPatientId(String patientId) {
        this.patientId = patientId;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void addVisit(MyPtVisit ptVisit) {
        visits.add(ptVisit);
    }

    public List<MyPtVisit> getVisits() {
        // create new ArrayList to hold copy
        List<MyPtVisit> copyVisits = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MyPtVisit myPtVisit : visits) {
            // use MyPtVisit's copy constructor to create a new MyPtVisit
            copyVisits.add(new MyPtVisit(myPtVisit));
        }
        return copyVisits;
    }

    public void setVisits(List<MyPtVisit> visits) {
        this.visits = visits;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyPatient [patientId=" + patientId + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", firstName="
                + firstName + ", visits=" + visits + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((patientId == null) ? 0 : patientId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MyPatient other = (MyPatient) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        if (patientId == null) {
            if (other.patientId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!patientId.equals(other.patientId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

// my patient visit
// holds information for each patient's visit to the doctor
class MyPtVisit {
    public static final String[] HEADINGS = { "Cost", "Chief Symptom", "Treatment" };
    private double cost;
    private String symptom;
    private String treatment;

    public MyPtVisit(double cost, String symptom, String treatment) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.symptom = symptom;
        this.treatment = treatment;
    }

    // copy constructor
    public MyPtVisit(MyPtVisit original) {
        this.cost = original.cost;
        this.symptom = original.symptom;
        this.treatment = original.treatment;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getSymptom() {
        return symptom;
    }

    public void setSymptom(String symptom) {
        this.symptom = symptom;
    }

    public String getTreatment() {
        return treatment;
    }

    public void setTreatment(String treatment) {
        this.treatment = treatment;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyPtVisit [cost=" + cost + ", symptom=" + symptom + ", treatment=" + treatment
                + "]";
    }

}
```